# Get data from multiple tables based on a ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a 2 table in mysql db. I want to get all data from those 2 table. Table name is following

1. `tutor_signup_form`
2. `tutor_signup_edu_psle`

So that I'm using following sql query but can't get the result.

```
$tutor_id =  (int) $_GET['tutor_id'];

$query =  mysql_query("SELECT  tutor_signup_form . *, tutor_signup_edu_psle . * FROM 
tutor_signup_form INNET JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psle ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = '$tutor_id'");
$result =  mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Note: Both table have same `tutor_id` column.

**New Update for 3 table:**

```
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT tutor_signup_form . *, tutor_signup_edu_psle . *,   
tutor_signup_edu_olevel . * FROM tutor_signup_form

INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psle ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_form.tutor_id , 

INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_olevel ON  tutor_signup_form.tutor_id =  
tutor_signup_edu_olevel.tutor_id 

where tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = '$tutor_id' ");

$result =  mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
SELECT  * FROM 
tutor_signup_form  ts1 INNER JOIN 
tutor_signup_edu_psle  ts2 ON ts1.tutor_id = ts2.tutor_id
and ts1.tutor_id='$tutor_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query should be like this, also you can use alias for table names

```
 $query =  mysql_query("SELECT tf.*, te.* FROM tutor_signup_form AS tf INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psle AS te ON tf.tutor_id = te.tutor_id WHERE tf.tutor_id = '$tutor_id'");
```

may this work for you

Answer (score 0):

in ON your can not give $tutor_id you need to give other table column reference like

```
ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_form.tutor_id
```

and give the filter of $tutor_id in where clause. So you query will look like

```
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT  tutor_signup_form . *, tutor_signup_edu_psle . * FROM 
tutor_signup_form INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psle ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_form.tutor_id where tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = '$tutor_id'");
```

Also i see you misspelled your INNER JOIN to INNET JOIN.

Comment: Hi, I've another table called `tutor_signup_edu_olevel` and check my update question. Now why it's not working ?

Comment: are you getting any error? also as you are using joins it may be possible matching data is not found.

Comment: yes, I'm getting error. I want to get all data from multiple table based on a `$tutor_id`.

Comment: error in this line "INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_olevel ON  tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_form.tutor_id" it should be tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = tutor_signup_edu_olevel.tutor_id. This are really silly copy paste mistakes :)

Comment: Still now I can't get the result. Please see update.

Comment: Hi, Did you see my new update. Now It's showing my this error message : `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\software installed\xampp installed\htdocs\tutor\toplevel\edit_tutor.php on line 34`. Do you know why ?

Comment: its something related to php. sorry i can't help you for this. may be you can google or open up new question.